# Representation of Poincaré group

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, group-representations, poincare-symmetry

Let's consider the most general Lorentz transformation: $x'^{\mu} = \Lambda^{\mu}_{\ \ \nu} x^{\nu} + a^{\mu}$. These transformations form the Poincaré group. The generators of translations of this group, $P^{\mu}$, commute between themselves, so we can find common eigenstates for them

$$P^{\mu} |p, \sigma \rangle = p^{\mu} |p, \sigma \rangle$$

Now, consider the operator $U(\Lambda,a) = e^{i(\omega_{\mu \nu}J^{\mu \nu} + a_{\mu}P^{\mu})}$, where the $J^{\mu \nu}$ are the generators of the Lorentz group. If I consider $a = 0$, I can show that $U(\Lambda) | p, \sigma \rangle $ is an eigenstate of the operator $P^{\mu}$ with eigenvalue $\Lambda^{\mu}_{\ \ \nu} p^{\nu}$, so I can write

$$U(\Lambda) | p, \sigma \rangle = \sum_{\sigma'} C_{\sigma, \sigma'}(\Lambda, p) | \Lambda p, \sigma' \rangle $$

I know that the matrices $\{C_{\sigma, \sigma'}(\Lambda, p)\}$ form a representation of the Poincaré group, but is it irreducible? Why? And, if it's really irreducible, since I am taking $a = 0$, shouldn't it be only a representation of the Lorentz group?

Comment: You didn't actually say anything here that uniquely determines *what* representation you're talking about, so one cannot show that it is irreducible, either.

Comment: Indeed, it need not be irreducible. But the point is that you can always reduce the range of $\sigma$ so that it is, in fact, irreducible. That is, you may always break a reducible representation into its irreducible parts, by definition.